# Jehora Jeheyu's Chaos boon in Desktop Dungeons

Tags: desktop-dungeons-2010

[The wiki says:](http://www.qcfdesign.com/wiki/DesktopDungeons/index.php?title=Gods#Jehora_Jeheyu)

> - Jehora Jeheyu
> - Boon: Chaos
> - Cost: All Piety
> - Effect: Either death or restore full health or mana or death.
>
>   - Success correlates to amount of remaining piety (which is 0)

What does this mean? Remaining piety will always be zero because it costs all piety. So how much would I need to restore my full health/mana? It seems that the more piety I use the larger the chance that I live, but is there a fixed "threshold" as to how much piety I should have so I won't die?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DDWiki (Jehora_Jeheyu)](http://www.qcfdesign.com/wiki/DesktopDungeons/index.php?title=Jehora_Jeheyu) suggests the following:

**Chaos**

- Randomly choose one of the following
  effects: Restore Health and Mana to
  Maximum / instant death.
- Costs ALL Piety you currently have.

  - Upon acquiring this boon, Jehora
    Jeheyu will either restore your
    Health and Mana to its Maximum
    capacity, or he will kill you
    outright. If death is chosen, it is
    immediate and cannot be avoided
    through the Protection from Death
    ability.
  - This boon has a chance for healing as
    opposed to death, roughly equal to
    the piety spent on the boon (all of
    your current piety, in other words).
    Therefore, if you have 60 piety when
    taking the boon, you have a 60%
    chance for a full heal, and a 40%
    chance for instant death.
  - *Research info required: Confirm the
    probability mechanism.*

Comment: oh i didn't check the specific god page. thanks for that